# Problem with the answer of a basic ratio problem

Tags: ratio

Here is the [solved example](http://www.proprofs.com/sat/study-guide/Topic1/N_O_M1_S1/html/6003.shtml).

The answer given is 175, but my calculation comes out to be 375. I thought that it was just a typo, but it has been written twice, so I'm not sure. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo. $(3/4)\cdot500=375$.

Comment: Thanks, accepting in 10 minutes. :)